# How to update document data which located inside a subcollection in Firebase & Nuxt

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My firestore structure

```
Subwork Package (collection)
        - UID (document)
                - Subwork Registration (subcollection)
                        - Doc unique ID (document)
                                - data etc etc
        - UID (document)
```

I have a table that displays all the documents that I have, inside the "Subwork Registration" subcollection.

```
//LOAD DATA TO TABLE IS SUCCESS
initializeTable() {
    this.SubworkTable = [];
    firestore
        .collectionGroup("Subwork Registration")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.SubworkTable.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
            })
        })
}
```

Then, I will pick one of the docs and edit/update its content from the list of docs that shows on the table. But when I do as below, I got into an error `.collectionGroup("").doc("") is not a function` kind of error

```
data: () => ({
    editedItem: {
        v-model: '',
        v-model: '',
        // etc etc
   }
})

//METHODS: {}
UpdateTable() {
    var data = {
        //
    };
    firestore
        .collectionGroup("Subwork Registration")
        .doc(this.editedItem.id)
        .update(data)
        .then(() => {
            //
        })

}
```

I do take note that we cannot update or set if we do `.collectionGroup("Subwork Registration").doc()` but Im not sure how to do it the right way (to edit/update document inside a subcollection).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To write a document in Firestore you will need to know the complete path to that document.

I recommend either keeping the `DocumentReference` if you can (as that already contains the entire path to the document), or alternative store the [`doc.ref.path`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path) for each document instead of `doc.id` as you do now.